# VBA in Excel 365: XMLHTTP - Can't search for presence of multiple strings for URLs?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

So I have a long list of URLs in an Excel sheet. Using a VBA macro I'm checking for the presence of a number of strings in each URL's HTML. I need to know which URL has which combination of strings in them.

I'm outputting the presence or absence of the strings in the main table as essentially: URL being looked at - col 1, presence of 1st string in that URL? - col 2, presence of 2nd string in that URL? - col 3

(And if I can work out how to get this code working, I'll be checking for a few more strings and outputting their presence or absence in further columns).

The strings I'm searching for are encoded into the VBA string.

My code works fine if I'm just searching for the 1st string.
When I adjust the code to search for a 2nd string as well, it doesn't output as it should if my 2nd string is present too.

I'm using a PC, MS Excel 2007 (it's the MS 365 suite on a Lenovo brought this year with Windows 10. I think I'm messing up something easy in the code here, but I can't quite work out how to search for multiple strings rather than just one, and output which ones are present in separate columns next to the URL in question.

Here's the whole code:

```
 Option Explicit
    
    Sub SearchForString()
       Dim rngURL As Range
       Dim cll As Range
       Dim stCheck As String
       Dim xmlHttp As Object
        
       On Error Resume Next
       Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
       If xmlHttp Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "Unable to create XMLHTTP object, it's probably not installed on this machine", vbCritical
          Exit Sub
       End If
       
       Set rngURL = Application.InputBox("Select the range of URLs to check", "Select Range", Selection, Type:=8)
       On Error GoTo 0
       
       If rngURL Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       
       stCheck = "Stringtofind1"
    
       If Len(stCheck) = 0 Then Exit Sub
       
       For Each cll In rngURL.Cells
          If CheckURL(xmlHttp, cll.Value, stCheck) Then
             cll.Offset(, 1).Value = "1st string found"  'This all works fine
            End If
    
            ' ** Start of Bit I can't get to work **
            ' ** I want to check for a second string, and see if that's here. But I can't seem to get this bit to work? **
          
              If CheckURL(xmlHttp, cll.Value, "2ndStringtofind") Then
              cll.Offset(, 2).Value = "2nd string also found"
              End If
          
            ' ** End of Bit I can't get to work ** 
     
       Next cll
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Function CheckURL(ByRef xmlHttp As Object, ByVal URL As String, ByVal stCheck As String) As Boolean
       Dim stResult As String 
       
       If Not LCase$(URL) Like "https://*" Then
          URL = "https://" & URL
            
       End If
       
       xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
       xmlHttp.Send ""
         
       If xmlHttp.readyState = 4 Then
          If xmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
             stResult = xmlHttp.responseText
             
             If InStr(1, stResult, stCheck, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                CheckURL = True   'Returns position where string is found!
           
             End If
         End If
       End If
    End Function
```

To make it easier to read, here's the bit where I think that I'm struggling when I add it to the script:

```
  If CheckURL(xmlHttp, cll.Value, "2ndStringtofind") Then
  cll.Offset(, 2).Value = "2nd string also found"
  End If
```

2ndStringtofind isn't a variable, but the actual text I'm looking for.

All help gratefully received in debugging this code. Thanks guys.

Comment: I would return `stResult` from the function `CheckURL` and conduct the second 'Instr' operation in the Main procedure. What's your beef with the result you get?

Comment: You don't want to make two requests for each url as per @Variatus's comment. Make CheckUrl something like CheckResponse and pass in the responseText as an argument and the search string as another. Return a boolean for if Instr > 0 for substring to search. In main sub have your loop over urls and you initial function call to return the responseText, then your two calls to search for items (or make it one function call with regex search and check the matches count and return match(es)). Remember to clear the stored response before looping back round by setting to vbNullString